# Windows vs Linux - math result difference

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I have program in C++. If I run same part of code, Linux and Windows are giving different results.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cfloat>
#include <cstdio>



#define MPI 3.141592653589793238462
#define DEG_TO_RAD(x) ((x) * 0.0174532925)
#define cot(x)  (1.0 / tan(x))
#define sec(x)  (1.0 / cos(x))

double p1 = DEG_TO_RAD(35);
double p2 = DEG_TO_RAD(65);

double lambertN = log(cos(p1) * sec(p2));
lambertN /= (log(tan(0.25 * MPI + 0.5 * p2) * cot(0.25 * MPI + 0.5 * p1)));


double t = tan(0.25 * MPI + 0.5 * p1);
double lambertF = cos(p1) * pow(t, lambertN);

//---------------------------

//specify input coordinates in degrees
double lon = 160.25;
double lat = 245.75;

double longitude = DEG_TO_RAD(lon - 10);
double latitude  = DEG_TO_RAD(lat);

double c = cot(0.25 * MPI + 0.5 * latitude);
double lambertPhi = lambertF * pow(c, lambertN);

printf("%f", lambertPhi); // here I got different results on Win and Linux
```

On Windows, I got correct result (or it seems so, because final result is OK).
On Linux, I got `NaN` or some very small numbers in comaprison to Windows.

What am I missing ?

**EDIT #1:**

**Windows** - Visual Studio 2010 - build via GUI

**Linux** - gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC)  - built with makefile, flags: CFLAGS = -lm -lstdc++  -Wall -O2

Both systems are 64bit

PS:
If anyone is interested, this is part of Lambert-Conic projection equation.

Comment: Are both OS'es 64bits? Your MPI definition seems to contain a lot of decimals

Comment: Yes.. both OS are 64bit (Windows7 and CentOS 5)

Comment: You should tell what compiler you are using. Also, this snippet is not enough to compile and try. What you can do yourself is stepping through this part of your program and compare values on both platforms to find out where both versions start to diverge.

Comment: because of libs and header files

Comment: I think we need a proper SSCCE, and precise details of the two environments. Compiler version, 32/64 bit etc.

Comment: @MartinPerry What are the types and values of lon and lat and please add the <cstdio> header for compilable code.

Comment: Also, if you need exact precision (no losses in the computation), don't use floats or doubles.

Comment: @ereOn, these computations don't look like they can be done without any loss in precision; after all OP is calling trigonometric functions and logarithms and so on.

Comment: I just chose the values `120` and `45` for `lon` and `lat`, respectively, and got a valid `0.686144` as output.  No `NaN` for me.  Please provide the `lon` and `lat` values for which you got your problem.

Comment: @Alfe: Makes sense. Altough I could easily imagine C++ libraries that can deal with such operations in a loss-less manner (like some calculators do). But that's probably out of scope here.

Comment: Since trigonometric functions mathematically return irrational numbers, this could only be done in a symbolic way (as in Mathematica or Maple or similar).  No arbitrary number class can do this without loss of precision.

Comment: Why can't we have an SSCCE? Don't you want an answer? Don't you want to be sure that we are compiling exactly the same code as you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, there is no real reason to expect the same results,
unless you take active steps to ensure specific results.  The
C++ language definition allows intermediate results to use
extended precision.  Typically, if a compiler does this (and
doing it is very frequent on an Intel architectures), The
extended precision will be truncated to standard double
precision when the compiler stores to memory.  And when it
stores to memory will depend on the internals of the compiler
(and probably even on the degree of optimization).

In the case of Intel, modern chips contain several floating
point processors: the older FPU uses extended precision, where
as the newer SSE variants don't.  But the newer SSE variants
aren't available on older processors.  By default, g++ (the
Linux compiler) uses the older FPU, to work everywhere, but
Visual C++, as far as I can tell, uses SSE.  This means that by
default, you will get different results.  Both compilers have
extensive options for changing this, but if you're running the
default configuration, I would *not* expect g++ and Visual to
give the same results.

Comment: Doesn't this depend if it's 32-bit or 64-bit code?  All 64-bit x86 processors have SSE so I thought GCC and MSVC both uses SSE by default for 64-bit code.  In 32-bit mode I don't know what the default is for either.

Comment: @Zboson It could.  I'm only using 32-bit mode at present, so I'm not sure what the defaults are in 64 bit mode.

Answer (score 1):

I get `nan`s for `lat` values between 90 and 270.  That seems reasonable because in that range the `cot()` will return a negative number which later cannot simply be raised to a fractional power with `pow`.

The question remains why you get different results on Windows for this.  But unless you provide information about the concrete input values I cannot say more.